# Passing Deep Linking "parameters" to a C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, macos, url, deep-linking

I'm currently struggling with a problem regarding Deep Linking for a C++ application: the current goal is to allow the user to take certain action in the app after clicking on a browser link. I didn't have any issues managing to allow the user to open the application using this... The issue comes when I try to make the application do something specific, depending on the URL's "parameters". Here's an example, to better illustrate my current goal:

If I open this link from a browser:

```
mybeautifulapp://action=banana
```

Then, the application should go to the "banana" section.

If I open this other link:

```
mybeautifulapp://action=apple
```

It should go to the "apple" section.

However, I have no idea where to get the URL's parameters themselves. I.e., everything after "mybeautifulapp://". Currently, I'm able to get the app to open using any of these URLs. **However, I'm not sure how to get the app to do something specific, depending on the URL's contents.**

I initially thought that the C++ app would receive the URL in its Main function arguments. I tried parsing them, but turns out that nothing related to the URL itself ever reaches the Main function. If that's the case, then, where can I receive the URL in order to parse it? I found a lot of information for Android, iOS, and Electron applications, but nothing for C++ apps

Comment: Hi @Noobuntu, did you get any results after these years?